# How to read NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I read the current value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in the oracle db?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In current sesion (client) settings:

```
select *
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

and in global database parameters:

```
select *
from nls_database_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/3282

Comment: Although a global setting exists, it is almost certainly not what you are interested in.  The number of places where the global setting is used is almost if not actually 0.  The session level setting always overrides the global setting and even scheduled database jobs set up their own NLS environment before running.