# ORA-01861 literal does not match format string error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hello Experts,

We have a requirement to find due date based on emp_id,

```
    create table emp_test (emp_id number, customer_due_date date)
    /
    create table dept_test (due_days number)
    /
```

```
    insert into emp_test values (1,sysdate)
    /
    insert into emp_test values (2,sysdate-1)
    /
    insert into emp_test values (3,sysdate-2)
    /
    insert into emp_test values (4,sysdate+1)
    /
    insert into emp_test values (5,sysdate+2)
    /
    insert into dept_test values(2)
    /
    commit
    /
```

My stored procedure:

```
    create or replace procedure test_proc(p_emp_id in emp_test.emp_id%type,p_due_date out date)
    as
    begin
    select
    (case
    when trim(to_char(trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r,due_days, 'Day')) = 'Sunday' then trunc(o.customer_due_date)-r.due_days-2
    when trim(to_char(trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r.due_days,
    'Day')) = 'Saturday' then trunc(o.customer_due_date)-r.due_days-1
    when trunc(o.customer_due_date) is null then trunc(sysdate) + 60
    else trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r.due_days
    end
    ) Due_date
    into p_due_date
    from
    dept_test r,
    emp_test o
    where o.emp_id = p_emp_id;

    p_due_date := to_char(p_due_date,'yyyy-mm-dd');

    end;
```

I am getting error as "ORA-01861 literal does not match format string".

Please suggest,how can we resolve the error?

Thanks.

Comment: `p_due_date := to_char(..)` make no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You are playing fast and loose with data types. Perhaps your programming experience is in a language (or languages) that does/do not enforce data types.

In the function declaration, you say that `p_due_date` will be of `DATE` data type. But when you first assign it (through `SELECT ... INTO`) you assign a string to it. Since you are not wrapping it in a proper `TO_DATE` function, Oracle (which enforces data types **sometimes** but not always, and many of its guesses are **plain wrong**) attempts to convert the string to a date before assigning to `p_due_date`, using your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. If that is not (by some accident) exactly 'yyyy-mm-dd', you will get this error.

The correct way to do this is to wrap the `CASE` expression, right in the `SELECT ... INTO` statement, within `TO_DATE()`.

By the way, later in the code you have `TO_CHAR(.....)` - why you have that, is completely unclear. `TO_CHAR` returns a string, but you are assigning back to `p_due_date` which must be a `DATE`, so you have even more implicit conversions (with the wrong format model). Of course, if you fix the `SELECT ... INTO` statement as I suggested, you don't need to do anything to `p_due_date` after it is selected into; you can return it as is.

Comment: could you please suggest what I need to change in select ..into .. statement

Comment: I already did. Put the case expression in that select within `to_date(...)`, as you were trying to do outside the select. If you are asking me to write the code for you, word for word, sorry but I don't do that kind of work.

Comment: i've modified select as you suggested but earlier date was coming as '11-oct-17' now it got changed with '17-oct-11', i need in '2017-10-11' format.

Comment: select
to_date(  (case
    when trim(to_char(trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r,due_days, 'Day')) = 'Sunday' then trunc(o.customer_due_date)-r.due_days-2
    when trim(to_char(trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r.due_days,
    'Day')) = 'Saturday' then trunc(o.customer_due_date)-r.due_days-1
    when trunc(o.customer_due_date) is null then trunc(sysdate) + 60
    else trunc(o.customer_due_date) - r.due_days
    end
    ),'yyyy-mm-dd') Due_date
    into p_due_date
    from
    dept_test r,
    emp_test o
    where o.emp_id = 1;

Comment: I don't understand. `p_due_date` is of `DATE` data type. `DATE` data type does not have format; only string representation of `DATE` has a format. If you are just **returning** the date (to use in further calculations, such as in join conditions or WHERE clause) then leave it alone. Are you **displaying** the value? **Only then** do you need to convert it to string, using `to_char(p_due_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. But why do you need this? You said you need to write a procedure with a `DATE` out parameter; why do you need to show it in one format or another?

Comment: If you are simply displaying it in a tool like Toad or SQL Developer (on in SQL\*Plus), without any conversion on your part, the tool itself does the conversion for you, using your `nls_date_format` parameter, which is set to `dd-MON-rr`. Issue this command to change it: `alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'`. Note that when you start a new session tomorrow, the default will be reset; you can override that with a `login.sql` file... perhaps too much for now! Just remember the `alter session` command.

Comment: actually this procedure is getting called from front end application and they need p_due_date out parameter in yyyy-mm-dd format instead dd-mon-yy format, so trying to modify the procedure but not getting what to change to get the value in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: alter session is hampering other procedure and UI application format, so can't do that.

Comment: Ugh... I didn't read carefully what you were doing in the rest of the procedure. Your CASE expression already returns a DATE, not a string. Wrap it within TO_CHAR(....) with the same format mask. But **change** the data type of the out parameter: it should be VARCHAR2(20) rather than DATE.

Comment: @mathguy: I don't agree with the solution to return varchar2 instead of date - whoever calls this procedure should deal with date properly. Database layer should not do such conversions unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @GoranStefanović - It depends. "Whoever calls this procedure" may be unable to deal with date properly. What I would do in that case is still write "this" procedure to return a date. Then I would write one more procedure to convert a date to a string, and use it only when needed (such as, to feed such inflexible callers). In any case, I just realized this is the same question I have been avoiding on OTN for a few days; my contribution to this thread has come to an end.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this row :

```
 p_due_date := to_char(p_due_date,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

you get this error.

Since p_due_date is a `date`, whereas assignment yields a `char`.

By the way, there's also a problem on 6th row of procedure, because of `,` in `r,due_days`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said

```
p_due_date := to_char(p_due_date,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

seems to be the problem. If what you're trying to do is to remove the time portion of the date value, I suggest you use

```
p_due_date := TRUNC(p_due_date);
```

instead.

Best of luck.

Comment: p_due_date := TRUNC(p_due_date); is also giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As *mathguy* said in his answer, this issue could happen when some connection parameters such as `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, `NLS_TIME_FORMAT`, etc are different from the DB server. In my case, I'm using the Symfony framework and its parameters were different from my Oracle server. So I have to edit my code to alter the session with raw SQL before and after my query execution:

```php
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

// Same parameters as DB server
$sqlAlterSession = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SSXFF' NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR'";
$conn->executeUpdate($sqlAlterSession);

// Execute your query
$sql = '...';
$conn->execute($sql);

// Restore original Symfony parameters
$sqlAlterSession = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS' NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'";
$conn->executeUpdate($sqlAlterSession);
```

All the DB server's parameters were retrieved following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941877/7058363) with **every** parameter in the `ALTER SESSION ...` sentence.